# i want to view pdf from firebase database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = Get.size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("PDF View"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('myorders')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                return SizedBox(
                    height: size.height,
                    width: size.width,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SfPdfViewer.network(
                          x['file'],
                          controller: _pdfViewerController,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ));
```

Error:

> RenderConstrainedOverflowBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
> This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload a file to the Firestore database it is a no-SQL database that stores data as key, value pairs contained within documents. These documents make up collections.
If you want to store PDFs, you have a few options, two of which would be either to:

- upload the file to Firebase Cloud Storage and then save the URI in the Firestore database
- convert the PDF (if small enough in size) to base64 to save as a string in Firestore, and then when retrieving the data convert it back

Comment: i want to view pdf from firebase firestore database